# Node "Recipe" For Asphalt?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

Is there any sort of node "recipe" or tricks for making asphalt? I'm making a road and I was wondering if there is a way of using shaders and/or other things in the editor to make it look more realistic?

This is intended for use in Cycles.

Comment: @someonewithpc I've posted a meta on this: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/569/599

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would start with a Voronoi texture as displacement map to get the "pebbles", then disrupt that texture with other kinds of noise.

[image]

[image]

[image]